# Why shouldn't you allow phones to be used both for password resets and multi-factor authentication in AWS Cognito?

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm going through the User Pools setup process and there's the following sentence under the **MFA and verifications** page:

> We recommend not allowing phone to be used for both password resets and multi-factor authentication (MFA).

What's the reason behind that recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the password reset and MFA are both sent via SMS, it's not true MFA. You want MFA to be configured on a different channel so an attacker who has your phone or SIM cannot reset your password **and** get an MFA code.

Comment: Hence the "multi-factor" part, right? It makes sense.